# How to disable specific cipher suites from HAPROXY - Can I do this "ssl-default-bind-ciphers no RC4-MD5"

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, haproxy

How to disable specific cipher suites from Haproxy?

All the documents say is to provide a list to be allowed for 'ssl-default-bind-ciphers'. I want to provide only the ones NOT to be allowed. Can I do this "ssl-default-bind-ciphers no RC4-MD5"

Reason: I don't want to restrict myself to the ones I put in the list. If the client comes in with a better, faster ciphers suite- I want the negotiations to go through.
I'm also not an expert in deciding which cipher suites need to be allowed. I have a list of weak ciphers that are to be disabled and I want to achieve just that.

Answer (score 2):

I found out a way to do that you put ! in front of the cipher suites you want to disable and that works. Well you do have to mention the list of suites that are needed as well without the ! - its not what I wanted but works.

Answer (score 0):

Per comment below, you are able to use the `!` to specify ciphers to refuse. Thanks @DivyaTV

It's worth noting that in order to exclude specific ciphers, you must include the ones you want.

For example:

```
ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:!ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH+CHACHA20:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
```

Another example: https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/

Ciphers: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html

Comment: I found out a way to do that  you put ! in front of the cipher suites you want to disable and that works. Well you do have to mention the list of suites that are needed as well without the ! - its not what I wanted but works.

Comment: Updated answer to include your find!

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered if my answer suffices?